# Python recursion with a nested list

Tags: python, list, recursion, nested

I am trying to make a recursive function that goes through any level of nested list with single character strings and returns True or False whether a given character is in that list.

This is my code:

```
def inlist(character, lists):
    """Checks if a given character is in a list of any level"""
    
    if lists[0] == character:
        return True
    
    elif isinstance(lists[0], list):
        return inlist(character,lists[0])
    
    elif not lists[0] == character:
        return inlist(character,lists[1:])
    
    else:
        return False
```

When i run the code with: ("c", [["a", "b","c", "d"],"e"])

it seems to be working fine. However, when i am typing the list in this way: ("c", [["a", "b",],["c", "d"],"e"])

It gives me an error, which says: **IndexError: list index out of range**

Can i not write a nested list in this way? If so, why?
Or is there anything wrong with my code that makes it not go through the whole list?

Comment: Note how you're doing `lists[0]` before checking if `lists` has any elements.

Comment: Hmm, would it be better if i had another if statement on top with that and indented everything else?

Comment: I would just turn your current `if` into an `elif`, then have the `if` something like `if not list:`. No need to nest.

Comment: You logic is a little flawed too, if the first element is a list with out the character the `elif` will fire and return False even though one of the later lists might have returned True.

Comment: I have added the top `If`, but what should it return if there is no elements left?

Comment: Mark, do you have any comment on which order it should be executed? Having a little trouble understanding

Comment: @Wups Slicing is actually safe to do on an empty list. It's a nice feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going for the the purely recursive approach, like it is used in the question:

```
def inlist(char, lists):
    if not lists: # check for empty list
        return False
        
    if lists[0] == char:
        return True

    elif isinstance(lists[0], list) and inlist(char, lists[0]):
        return True # return only if found in sublist, otherwise continue

    elif len(lists) > 1: # check rest of the list, if there is a rest
        return inlist(char, lists[1:])
        
    return False # all possibilities exhausted. Char not in this (sub-)list
```

This can be useful for some problems, but to find an element in a list, a loop would be faster. Also, the max recursion depth will be a problem for longer lists.

Answer (score 0):

You made it a bit complicated, while the way of thinking in case of recursion should be much simpler

**DFS-ish version:**

*(you can read more on DFS traversal all over the net)*

```
def inlist(character, lists):
    """Checks if a given character is in a list of any level"""
    for item in lists:
        if item==character:
            return True
        if isinstance(item, list):
            if inlist(character, item):
                return True
    return False
    
            
        
a = ["c", [["a", "b",],["c", "d"],"e"]]
print(inlist("a", a))
```

output:

```
True
```

for this input:

```
print(inlist("z", a))
```

output is:

```
False
```

*short explanation:*

- loop over all items in list
- if the item is the character - finish
- if the item is list - invoke recursion immediately (the catchy part here, is to return only if True, because if not - it not means that the character isn't found in other items)
- if finish over all items and not found - finish
- better when there is more chances that the item is in inner lists

**BFS-ish version:**

*(you can read more on BFS traversal all over the net)*

```
def inlist(character, lists):
    """Checks if a given character is in a list of any level"""
    extra_arr = []
    for item in lists:
        if item==character:
            return True
        if isinstance(item, list):
            extra_arr.append(item)
    
    for extra_item in extra_arr:
        if inlist(character, extra_item):
            return True
    return False
```

of-course, same results.

*short explanation:*

- loop over all items in list
- if the item is the character - finish
- if the item is list - append to `extra_arr` which will execute after verify all the items in the current level
- if finish over all items and not found - finish
- better when there is more chances that the item is in outer lists

Comment: This seems to be a much smarter and simpler solution, I will keep it in mind! I understand this is a mix of iteration and recursion. Is that the usual way to go about solving these problems? Or are there instances where only recursion is preferred?

Comment: I added some more "educational stuff" of DFS and BFS approaches, It mostly come from graphs traversals, but through my eyes it seems to be similar case in here. I don't know if there is any cut-and-clear definition of what is 'usual way', each person with his prefers I guess, more over it that I think that there is no relations between the recursion and iterations.

Answer (score 0):

@Wups has you covered for the purely recursive solution. And nice catch on the `isinstance(lists[0], list)` case where you must still be careful to check `lists[1]` if the recursive call returns false.

Always check if a list is empty *before* reaching in for a value. Here's another way to think about the problem using higher-order functions like, `some`.

```py
def some(f, t):
  if not t:
    return False
  else:
    return f(t[0]) or some(f, t[1:])

def inlist(char, ls):
  return some \
    ( lambda v: inlist(char, v) if isinstance(v, list) else char == v
    , ls
    )

input = ["c", [["a", "b",],["c", "d"],"e"]]
print(inlist("a", input))
print(inlist("z", input))
```

```
True
False
```

---

Above we write `some` as an exercise. You should be aware Python has a built-in `any` function -

```py
def inlist(char, ls):
  return any(isinstance(v, list) and inlist(char, v) or char == v for v in ls)

input = ["c", [["a", "b",],["c", "d"],"e"]]
print(inlist("a", input))
print(inlist("z", input))
```

```
True
False
```